# Django sitemap generates with double https:// when on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, sitemap, google-search-console

I am using the sitemap framework to generate a sitemap. The Google search console states that the sitemap is an invalid file format. It seems to be valid XML but the URL's in the sitemap have a double `https://` and I can't figure out why.

This only happens when hosting on Heroku and the allowed host in `settings.py` is set to the Heroku domain name. When I run the app locally with no allowed host the sitemap generates perfectly.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Sitemap:

```
<URL>
<loc>https://https://swflreliefrealty.herokuapp.com/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<URL>
<loc>https://https://swflreliefrealty.herokuapp.com/contact/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

Django `sitemap.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse
from blog.models import Post

class StaticViewSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'daily'
    priority = '0.5'

    def items(self):
        # Return list of url names for view to include in sitemap
        return ['home', 'contact', 'success', 'blog']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)

class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'daily'
    priority = '0.5'
    def items(self):
    return Post.objects.all()
```

Django `settings.py`:

```
import os



# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['swflreliefrealty.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sendemail.apps.SendemailConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps', 
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'robots',
    'blog'

]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `sites.Site` model has its `domain` set to `https://swflreliefrealty.herokuapp.com` in your production database. The sites framework [is used by the sitemap framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#installation).

The site's `domain` [should *just* be set to the domain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site.domain), without protocol, e.g. `swflreliefrealty.herokuapp.com`.

Since this is stored in your database, it could easily have a different value in production (on Heroku, where it doesn't work) and development (locally, where it does).